# How do I display the price from Amazon products with API?

Tags: product, price, amazon-product-api

I had my associates account closed by Amazon because I've entered my prices manually and I need to enter them using Product Advertising API so they'll be up to date every time. I just don't know exactly how to use that. I've tried with "Amazon Product in a Post" plugin but [it shows the picture too](http://therightgiftideas.com/gift/sofa/) while I'd like it to display just the price. If you guys know how to get rid of the picture or another way to insert the price with API, it would be a life saver.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to remove picture with class amazon-image-wrapper in you page, and so you keep amazon api plugin:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    $("amazon-image-wrapper").remove();
</script>
```

Don't forget to add jQuery in the head of the page:

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```